# How many statistical possibilities can an 8x4 grid with 4 evenly-distributed colors produce?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I'm making a visual hash for an application and I'm curious how many possible combinations this visual hash can produce.

Imagine an $8\times 4$ grid that must be colored in evenly by 4 colors whereby each color fills in 8 random squares on the grid. There are no other rules for distribution. How would one calculate the number of possibilities this visual hash can produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose 8 cells from 32 to be one color, then choose next 8 from 24 to be second color and so on... So we have $${32\choose 8}{24\choose 8}{16\choose 8}{8\choose 8}= {32!\over 8!^4}$$

Comment: 99 quadrillion possibilities... mind has been boggled.

Comment: Equivalently, colour the cells 8 shades of red, 8 shades of yellow, 8 shades of green, 8 shades of blue, that’s 32 colours in 32 boxes, that’s $32!$, then merge all the reds (discarding the sequence information within the reds divides by $8!$), ditto yellows (another $8!$), ditto greens, ditto blues.